# Working with pipes in Unix C

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I am having serious trouble working with pipes in C. I'm supposed to take in arguments from the command line (example: ./myprogram 123 45 67), read the arguments one character at a time into a buffer, send the character to the child process to be counted, and then return the total number of characters read to the parent process. My code is as follows(note: the comments are what I'm supposed to be doing):

```
// Characters from command line arguments are sent to child process
// from parent process one at a time through pipe.
// Child process counts number of characters sent through pipe.
// Child process returns number of characters counted to parent process.
// Parent process prints number of characters counted by child process.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

static int toChild[2];
static int fromChild[2];
static char buffer;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status;
    int nChars = 0;
    pid_t   pid;

    pipe(toChild);
    pipe(fromChild);

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        printf("fork error %d\n", pid);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        close(toChild[1]);
        close(fromChild[0]);
        // Receive characters from parent process via pipe
        // one at a time, and count them.

        int count = 0;
        printf("child about to read\n");
        while(read(toChild[0], &buffer, 1)){
            count++;
        }
        // Return number of characters counted to parent process.

        write(fromChild[1], &count, sizeof(count));
        close(toChild[0]);
        close(fromChild[1]);
        printf("child exits\n");
    }
    else {
        close(toChild[0]);
        close(fromChild[1]);
        // -- running in parent process --
        printf("CS201 - Assignment 3 - Chris Gavette\n");

        write(toChild[1], &argv[1], 1); 

        // Send characters from command line arguments starting with
        // argv[1] one at a time through pipe to child process.

        read(fromChild[0], &nChars, 1);

        // Wait for child process to return. Reap child process.
        // Receive number of characters counted via the value
        // returned when the child process is reaped.
        close(toChild[1]);
        close(fromChild[0]);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        printf("child counted %d chars\n", nChars);
        printf("parent exits\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The child process seems to hang even though I've closed both ends of both pipes.

Comment: You have two `fork` calls in this. You know that, right? The second one blindly overrides the pid returned from the first. Take out the first one. Then consider all the read/write calls you're performing and ask yourself how **big** the things being sent back and forth are. Ex: `write(toChild[1], &count, 1)`. Um, `count` is `int`; why are you only sending one byte and not `sizeof(count)` ? And your child-loop-exit condition is iffy-at-best. Finally, in case you didn't realize it; you should use **two** pipe descriptor pairs for this; not one.

Comment: Aha, thank you. That solves the twice-called problem.

Comment: And I figured out that I needed two file descriptors for this a minute or two after I posted this question. I feel dumb, as that should have been obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, this is wrong.

```
write(toChild[1], &count, 1)
```

It will eventually contribute to your problem. `count` is a `int`, not `char` or `unsigned char`. You need to send `sizeof(count)`. Also, the read-function upon hitting an *error* will return EOF, which is non-zero, so your child exit condition is not appropriate. it should look something like this:

```
while(read(toChild[0], &buffer, 1) == 1)
```

Finally, your parent process should cycle through each argument in `argv[]` sending each as a `strlen` sized buffer.

I'm nearly certain this is what you're trying to do. Note that in order to maintain sanity in knowing which descriptor is used for a specific purpose, I prefer using a `#define` to note what each process uses for reading and writing. This can be extended to any number of processes, btw, which I'm sure is not too far down the line for your next assignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

// P0_READ   - parent read source
// P0_WRITE  - parent write target
// P1_READ   - child read source
// P1_WRITE  - child write target

#define P0_READ     0
#define P1_WRITE    1
#define P1_READ     2
#define P0_WRITE    3
#define N_PIPES     4

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[N_PIPES], count = 0, i;
    pid_t pid;
    char c;

    if (pipe(fd) || pipe(fd+2))
    {
        perror("Failed to open pipe(s)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // fork child process
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to fork child process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // child process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // close non P1 descriptors
        close(fd[P0_READ]);
        close(fd[P0_WRITE]);

        // get chars from input pipe, counting each one.
        while(read(fd[P1_READ], &c, 1) == 1)
            count++;

        printf("Child: count = %d\n", count);
        write(fd[P1_WRITE], &count, sizeof(count));

        // close remaining descriptors
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    // parent process. start by closing unused descriptors
    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

    // send each arg
    for (i=1; i<argc; ++i)
        write(fd[P0_WRITE], argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));

    // finished sending args
    close(fd[P0_WRITE]);

    // Wait for child process to return.
    wait(NULL);

    // wait for total count
    if (read(fd[P0_READ], &count, sizeof(count)) == sizeof(count))
        printf("Parent: count = %d\n", count);

    // close last descriptor
    close(fd[P0_READ]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
./progname argOne argTwo
```

**Output**

```
Child: count = 12
Parent: count = 12
```

---

**Edit: Single Pipe with Child Return Status**

It seems from the comments of the original question your assignment may call for reaping the return status of the *child* process as the result count rather than returning it in a pipe. In doing so, you can do this with a single pipe-descriptor pair. I prefer the first method, but this works as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

// P0_WRITE  - parent write target
// P1_READ   - child read source

#define P1_READ     0
#define P0_WRITE    1
#define N_PIPES     2

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[N_PIPES], count = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    char c;

    if (pipe(fd))
    {
        perror("Failed to open pipe(s)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // fork child process
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to fork child process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // close non P1 descriptors
        close(fd[P0_WRITE]);

        // Return number of characters counted to parent process.
        while(read(fd[P1_READ], &c, 1) == 1)
            ++count;

        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        printf("Child: count = %d\n", count);
        return count;
    }

    // parent process. start by closing unused descriptors
    close(fd[P1_READ]);

    // eacn each arg entirely
    for (int i=1; i<argc; ++i)
        write(fd[P0_WRITE], argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));

    // finished sending args
    close(fd[P0_WRITE]);

    // Wait for child process to return.
    if (wait(&count) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to wait for child process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Parent: count = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(count));

    return 0;
}
```

The results are the same, but note this is a biach to to debug as most debuggers will signal-trip on your child process and the real exit status is lost. On my Mac, for example, running this under Xcode trips:

```
Failed to wait for child process: Interrupted system call
```

while running from the command line gives:

```
Child: count = 12
Parent: count = 12
```

One of the many reasons I prefer the two-pipe methodology.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed to program to output. The hanging problem must have been a result of my misunderstanding of the read/write functions. I really appreciate this!

Comment: @user3698112 glad it helped. Do try and use macros or symbolic constants of some form for your indexes into pipe-descriptor pairs/arrays at least until you get a handle on them. It will ultimately make them easier to **read**, much-less write code against. The intent in the posted code of this answer should be much more intuitive with those symbols rather than `[1]` or `[3]`, etc. Best of luck.

Comment: I appreciate the advice about readable code. That's something I've been trying to work on lately, and most of the time, I think I do it fairly well, but this assignment was just giving me so much trouble that I slapped it into a question with little editing. Anyway, I really appreciate the help and I'll try to take your advice to heart!

Comment: @user3698112 Added single pipe version as well, which I think is likely one of the goals of your assignment. It has caveats, so read the posted comments. Glad to help.

Comment: IN looking at the 2 pipe example, I think it will not work for returning the value from the child.  Because pipes do not work if the sender end is closed,  so the wait(null) should be after reading the child to parent value